# Show entire MongoDB contents in Node.js API

Tags: node.js, mongodb

First off, don't worry, it's a tiny data set - I realise it wouldn't be wise to dump an entire production DB to a single screen via an API... I just need to get a JSON dump of entire (small) DB to return via an API endpoint in a Node.js application.

My application does successfully return single records with this code:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/search", function (err, db) {

    if(err) throw err;

    db.collection('results', function(err, collection) {
        // search for match that "begins with" searchterm
        collection.findOne({'string':new RegExp('^' + searchterm, 'i')}, function(err, items){
            // get result
            var result;
            if (items == null || items.result == null){
                result = "";
            }
            else {
                result = items.result;
            }
            // return result
            res.send(result);
        });
    });
});
```

So I know Node is talking to Mongo successfully, but how can I tweak this query/code to basically return what you get when you execute the following on the MongoDB command line:

```
$ db.results.find()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I appreciate your answers pointing me in the right direction, in terms of using {} as the query. Here is the code that eventually worked for me:

```
db.collection('results', function(err, collection) {
    collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        res.send(docs);
    });
});
```

The crucial element being the *toArray(...)* part.

Comment: I've very curious as to why you needed to tack `toArray` on. Mind sharing what version of MongoDB/Mongoose you're using?

Comment: I'll be honest, I've no idea what Mongoose is. I'm running v3.2.0 of MongoDB on Mac OS X Sierra. I've used toArray(...) because after a lot of random trial and error, this is the first thing that worked. If you suggest a correct alternative I'll give that a go.

Comment: Mongoose is a wrapper around MongoDB for JavaScript/Node.js that abstract stuff into slightly more maintainable and readable code. I think that's why my suggested solution didn't work. Mongoose probably does exactly what you did: `toArray()` internally.

Answer (score 2):

This is snippet.

```
model.find({}).exec(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {console.error(err); return;}
        else return result;
    });
```

First use your predefined model and call find. the logic is to place a empty object `{}` essentially rendering . select all from this model.

Make sense?

Comment: i also recommend using promises, with mongodb. preferably bluebird.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as you've described it.

```
collection.find({}).exec((err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  if (result.length > 0) {
  // We check that the length is > 0 because using .find() will always
  // return an array, even an empty one. So just checking if it exists
  // will yield a false positive
  res.send(result);
  // Could also just use `return result;`
});
```